# this style of coding in android? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I don't understand how this code uses my `ListView` that I defined in layout file:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), 
         R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

can anyone explane me this and write another code simpler than this, that I use my own `ListView` with it's **ID**?

exactly: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a line just below it that looks like

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a simple provided list ***item*** layout.

to define your own `Adapter` I would extend `BaseAdapter` - you'll have to implement a number of methods - `getView` being one of them. `getView` is where you define your list ***item*** layouts.

```
class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // implement me
    ...
}
```

once you've done that, you can use it via

```
SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
// or, in your case
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: setListAdapter(adapter);
      getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: I have this lines after that. but I don't understand android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Comment: Within a `ListActivity`, `setListAdapter` probably internally uses `ListView#setAdapter`

Comment: I have this lines after that. but I don't understand android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Comment: I extended ListFragment class.

Comment: You can either a) define your own list adapter and use `getView` to define a custom item layout or b) use a simple adapter like the above and provide an item layout (in this case `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`)

Comment: yes `ListFragment`/`ListActivity` are pretty similar - both provide `setListAdapter` and both use `ListView#setAdapter` internally.

Comment: How I can define my own list adapter?